# Is the following true: log(k!)=O(k)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, logarithm

Is it correct to claim that log(k!)=O(k)? I searched for a proof but didn't find any on the web.

Answer (score 3):

No,
By Striling's approximation

```
k! ~ (k/e)^k * sqrt2 of (2*phi*k)
```

Therefore its Omega of (klogk) which is not O(k)
See the following:

Left side:

```
log(n!) = ...
```

[image]

Note: Sorry for this type of writing, still learning Stackoverflow math writing...

Comment: StackOverflow is not compatible with MathJax, thus your style of typing maths equations is good.